# Move Outlook incoming message to folder that starts with the same codes

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am trying to automate moving incoming messages to a designated subfolder in Outlook.

Messages that contain a projectnumber in the format P000.0000 should be moved to the Inbox's subfolder that starts with the same projectnumber.

The subfolders will be pre-created by hand, so the user can decide which projects to round up in a dedicated subfolder.

The folderstructure is Inbox>Actueel>P000.0000

The first bit, where incoming messages are checked works fine, but after that I get lost... Where it starts with `For Each Folder In olFolderPrjcts`

The error is on this line `Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`

This is what I came up with so far:

```
Private WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
      Set olApp = Outlook.Application
      Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
      Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
      Set myOlItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
  Dim Atts As Outlook.Attachments
  Dim Props As Outlook.UserProperties
  Dim Prop As Outlook.UserProperty
  Dim PropName As String

  PropName = "NumberAttachments"

  Set Atts = item.Attachments
  Set Props = item.UserProperties
  Set Prop = Props.Find(PropName, True)
  If Prop Is Nothing Then
    Set Prop = Props.Add(PropName, olText, True)
  End If

  Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

  Dim olFolderPrjcts
  Set olFolderPrjcts = olFolder.Folders("actueel")

  Prop.Value = Atts.Count
  item.Save

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item

    For Each Folder In olFolderPrjcts
        If Left(Msg.Subject, 9) = Left(Folder.Name, 9) Then
            Msg.Move (Folder)
        End If
    Next
' DO SOMETHING TO NEWLY ARRIVED MESSAGE
'     If Msg.Subject contains like P000.0000 AND
'       folder exists that starts with P000.0000
'       then move to that folder

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I know I still have to add code to make sure RE: and FWD: messages will be moved to the folder too, but one step at a time :)

Comment: As the programmer you do not get to use `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` especially when debugging. Delete it then edit your question as described here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. If that is not enough for you to fix any error that is now visible to you, include a description of the error and the line with the error.

Comment: Thank you @niton. I have edited my question as you suggested.

Comment: You forgot to state the error description. It is different when Option Explict is present or not. Add Option Explict to the top of the module if it is not there. Consider Option Explict to be mandatory. Tools | Options | Editor tab | Checkbox "Require Variable Declaration" for the future. You will get error messages for the undeclared variables objNS and Folder. So declare them and set objNS to something. While you are at it declare olFolderPrjcts as a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Option Explicit the error is likely Run-time error '424': Object required.

With Option Explicit the error is likely Compile error: Variable not defined.

```
Option Explicit

' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Checkbox "Require Variable Declaration"

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim objNS As Namespace  ' <--

    Dim olFolder As folder
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim olFolderPrjcts As folder

    Dim Msg As MailItem

    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")    ' <--

    Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olFolderPrjcts = olFolder.Folders("actueel")

    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then

        Set Msg = Item

        For Each folder In olFolderPrjcts.Folders
            If Left(Msg.subject, 9) = Left(folder.name, 9) Then
                'Debug.Print Msg.subject
                'Debug.Print folder.name
                Msg.move folder ' <-- no brackets
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

  End If

End Sub
```